# Select distinct returning duplicate results

Tags: sql, distinct, kentico

I'm trying to return the top n most read blog posts in a kentico site, but for some reason my query is returning two duplicate rows despite using the `DISTINCT` clause. The query is below:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3
       [BlogPostTitle]
      ,[BlogPostDate]
      ,[BlogPostSummary]
      ,[BlogPostBody]
      ,[BlogPostTeaser]
      ,[BlogPostAllowComments]
      ,[BlogPostPingedUrls]
      ,[BlogPostNotPingedUrls]
      ,[BlogLogActivity]
      ,[DocumentTags]
      ,[HitsStatisticsID]
      ,[HitsCount]
      ,[NodeAliasPath]
  FROM [AngliaRegistrars].[dbo].[Analytics_Statistics]

  INNER JOIN [AngliaRegistrars].[dbo].[Analytics_HourHits] ON HitsStatisticsID = StatisticsID
  INNER JOIN [AngliaRegistrars].[dbo].[View_CONTENT_BlogPost_Joined] ON StatisticsObjectID = DocumentNodeID

  WHERE StatisticsCode = 'pageviews' ORDER BY HitsCount DESC
```

Im not exactly the most experienced when it comes to writing SQL so hopefully it's something glaringly obvious that i've missed but it seems to make sense to me.

Any help is greatly appreciated

edit* [results of query](http://i49.tinypic.com/epexw0.png)

Comment: Please provide a sqlfiddle with a schema,sample data, and the query that is being executed. As it stands now there is not enough data to answer the question.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the records are exact duplicates?, can you show an example of your result set?

Comment: You have HitsCount in your result set. I would think that field would normally be different for each record.

Comment: @MichaelSallmen be that as it may, it seems like wild speculation no?

Comment: Not wild, but, yes, speculation. I think the OP is falling into the common trap of including more fields in a DISTINCT query that he really wants. I'm just trying to promote thought along that line.

Comment: @Duane There are missing columns on your image of the results of your query

Comment: I see your update please go to sqlfiddle.com and build a schema for us

Comment: @MichaelSallmen :) .  OP needs to provide us with a fiddle, or we won't be able to answer his question.

Comment: Just a guess, but group on DocumentID is probably what you want, then join back onto Analytics_Statistics to get the title, date, etc after doing the top N.

Comment: @Lamak My apologies, `HitsCount` is different between the two duplicate rows for some bizarre reason, but this is the only difference. So i guess `DISTINCT` really is returning unique results but not the kind of ones I want. Why was this downvoted? If i can improve the question, let me know.

Comment: @Duane - Then you should post a question explaining the results you want and then we can help you get there. But, for now, your question already has an explanation

Comment: It was downvoted because the problem you described doesn't actually exist.

Comment: @JNK I would have thought that obvious? What's more likely, a problem in my logic (hence the question) or that `DISTINCT` is somehow bugged? Anyway, I resolved this, inner joining on HitStatisticsID was the issue as there were some columns with the same ID, even though I was advised that this column contained unique data. Joining on HitsID gave me the desired results.

Answer (score 3):

This may be something you already looked at, but if you're using variable character length fields, you may have some non-visible characters or tabs included in the data that are affecting the results.  This would make it look like you have duplicates, but they really aren't.

Check the LEN() of the fields for a quick compare on the duplicates.  If you have different length on the fields you see as duplicates, try a TRIM() function on the column and see if that removes the duplicates.

Comment: See comment on the question where op says that the results are not exact duplicates.

Answer (score -4):

Include the table alias in your Select columns:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3
       a.[BlogPostTitle]
      ,a.[BlogPostDate]
      ,a.[BlogPostSummary]
      ,a.[BlogPostBody]
      ,a.[BlogPostTeaser]
      ,a.[BlogPostAllowComments]
      ,a.[BlogPostPingedUrls]
      ,a.[BlogPostNotPingedUrls]
      ,a.[BlogLogActivity]
      ,a.[DocumentTags]
      ,a.[HitsStatisticsID]
      ,a.[HitsCount]
      ,a.[NodeAliasPath]
  FROM [AngliaRegistrars].[dbo].[Analytics_Statistics]
  INNER JOIN [AngliaRegistrars].[dbo].[Analytics_HourHits] ON HitsStatisticsID = StatisticsID
  INNER JOIN [AngliaRegistrars].[dbo].[View_CONTENT_BlogPost_Joined] a ON StatisticsObjectID = DocumentNodeID
  WHERE StatisticsCode = 'pageviews' ORDER BY HitsCount DESC
```

DISTINCT can give mixed results when joining multiple tables. With this we make sure the query only returns distinct records of just that one table, in this case: "View_CONTENT_BlogPost_Joined"

Comment: I fail to see why would this be related to the problem

Comment: Out of curiosity, why will this work?

Comment: Because DISTINCT can give mixed results when joining multiple tables. With this we make sure the query only returns distinct records of just that one table, in this case: "View_CONTENT_BlogPost_Joined".

Comment: @CarlosMartinez This has nothing to do with that. Since op can actually run this query, it means that there is no ambiguous columns there, so the table alias (though a good practice) it's not a necesity, and does not affect the duplication of results